# complete indexing of text file java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

im trying to read a text file, sort the words within alphabetically and display what line numbers those words appear on.

Im new to java so not sure what the most efficient way to approach the system is.

My plan so far is to:

-use a `scanner` to parse file into one string
-`string.split` 
-`lineCount++`
-(somehow sort those split strings alphabetically)
-print sorted words with line number next to them

Is that the best way of going about this? im not sure if java has some sort of ordered dictionary maybe i could use?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/index.html has a good explanation of the basic java collections. Sort is available on any of these collections when you're using Strings.

Comment: You can define an Class composed by line number and text, implement `Comparable` interface, put them in a `List` and sort the `List` using `Collections.sort`method.

Answer (score 0):

A Scanner is fine, as you could scan per word, not even needing a split.
A BufferedReader would be for line-wise reading, and there exists a LineNumberReader for your goal: counting lines.

I head indicate the encoding of the file.

```
SortedMap<String, SortedSet<Integer>> linenosPerWord = new TreeMap<>();

// A BufferedReader with a linenumber counter:
try (LineNumberReader in = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputSTream(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
    for (;;) {
        String line = in.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            break;
        }
        int lineno = in.getLineNumber();
        String[] words = line.split("\\P{LM}"); // Split on non-letters and non-accents
        for (String word : words) {
            word = word.toLowerCase(); // Possible with Locale
            SortedSet<Integer> linenos = linenosPerWord.get(word);
            if (linenos == null) {
                linenos = new TreeSet<>();
                linenosPerWord.put(word, lineno);
            }
            linenos.add(lineno);
        }
    }
}
linenosPerWord.remove(""); // Remove a  possibly found empty word, like in "-Hello"
```

Comment: ah that looks like the stuff i need. I've put it in with some words to escape. But I'm getting that 'StandardCharsets.UTF_8' cannot be resolved to a variable?

Comment: You can use "UTF-8". [StandardCharset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html), since Java 7, lists Charset constants that are standard, always available, That prevents the need to treat UnsupportEncodingException.